# pg_total_relation_size is not as expected

Tags: postgresql

I have just cleared the table, but still pg_total_relation_size returns about 100 kB

```
DELETE FROM points;   
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"public"."points"'));
```

Do I have refresh something?

Answer (score 3):

No, usually you don't have to do anything. The space is available for use after deletes, but the table is not shrunk. If you really need to reclaim space, for example if you have filled up your hard drive with huge test tables, then you can do that with the [VACUUM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) command. `VACUUM FULL` will shrink all tables as much as possible.

Postgresql does not shrink/compact a table when rows are deleted. This is much cheaper for the database than reorganizing tables. The database will periodically run autovacuum to reclaim space.

Craig Ringer explains this better in a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15612822/1914376).

Here is some sample code for testing:

```
--#### Initialize test: Insert 99999 rows with test data
DROP SCHEMA testschema CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA testschema;

CREATE TABLE testschema.points (
   data text DEFAULT 'asjklfaskljgkljasklgjaskldjgklasjdgklasjdgkljasdghaskldvhajklnsefawegwafeawgfawegfadg'
);    

INSERT INTO testschema.points SELECT generate_series(1,99999);

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"testschema"."points"'));
--Output: 3567 kB


--##### Delete: Space is not released to the OS yet.
DELETE FROM testschema.points;

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"testschema"."points"'));
--Output: 3567 kB


--#### Vacuum: Table is compacted and space is released to the OS.
VACUUM FULL testschema.points;

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"testschema"."points"'));
-- Output: 8192 bytes
```